# Selenium C# : checking the broken links of the URL which has browser authentication

Tags: c#, selenium, automation

I have a browser authentication Url so if i am checking the Broken links its retrieving all the links and it shows as unauthorized 401 status code .so is it because of username and password embedded in the url ?
here is the code

```
 public void brokenlinksandimage1()
        {
            //links //a href 
            //images.......//img href
            //step1. get the list of all the links and images:

            IList<IWebElement> linklist = driver.FindElements(By.TagName("a"));

            //in the same linklist list add another attribute img is added to the list//
            IList<IWebElement> imagelist = driver.FindElements(By.TagName("img"));
            //list is created to store the a tag that has only href//
            List<IWebElement> validations = new List<IWebElement>();


            //foreach (IWebElement element in linklist)
            for (int k = 0; k < linklist.Count; k++)
            {
                //iterate the linklist excludes all the links/images-doesn't have the href attribute
                //int i = 0;
                //Check the first attribute of the fetched element whether it should not be null//
                //creating list only for the links that has href property active list contains only a tag an img tag that has href property //
                if (linklist[k].GetAttribute("href") != null)
                {//Adding the element to the validation list
                    validations.Add(linklist[k]);

                }
                Console.WriteLine(validations[k].GetAttribute("href"));

            }

            Console.WriteLine("The number of links :" + linklist.Count);

            Console.WriteLine("The number of links:" + validations.Count);

            //image list elements are added to the validations list//
            for (int j = 0; j < imagelist.Count; j++)

            {//Adding the element to the validation list

                if (linklist[j].GetAttribute("href") != null)
                {
                    validations.Add(imagelist[j]);
                }
                //Console.WriteLine(validations[j].GetAttribute("src"));
            }//get the size of the active list 
            Console.WriteLine("The number of Images:" + imagelist.Count);
            Console.WriteLine("The total number of images and links :" + validations.Count);

            //Step 3. check the href url,with httpconnection url//
            //200---->ok
            //400---->bad request
            //401----->unauthorised 
            //404--->Not found
            //500-----> Internal error
            //this is for links 
            int brokenlinkCount = 0;

            for (int i = 0; i < validations.Count; i++)
            {
                try
                {
                    //passing the Url in the validation list to the HTTPurl to open the connection will stored in the connection object //
                    HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection)new URL(validations[i].GetAttribute("href")).openConnection();
                    // connection.setRequestMethod("GET");
                    //connecting to the particular url


                    connection.setConnectTimeout(2000);

                    connection.connect();

                    ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback =
                        new RemoteCertificateValidationCallback(
                            delegate (object sender, X509Certificate certificate, X509Chain chain, SslPolicyErrors errors)
                            {
                                return true;


                            });


                    Thread.Sleep(2000);
                    // to get the response message after connection.
                    String response1 = connection.getResponseMessage();
                    //disconnect the connection
                    // connection.disconnect();
                    //printing the result with response//
                    Console.WriteLine(validations[i].GetAttribute("href") + "------->" + response1);

                    if (connection.getResponseCode() >= 400)
                    {

                        brokenlinkCount++;
                        Console.WriteLine(connection.getResponseMessage() + "is a broken link");
                    }

                    //Fetching and Printing the response code obtained
                    else
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine(connection.getResponseMessage() + "is a not broken link");
                    }


                }




                catch (Exception)
                {
                    // ActivityLog.InsertSyncActivity(ex);
                }
                Console.WriteLine("The total number of broken links are:" + brokenlinkCount);
                int brokenImagesCount = 0;
                for (int q = 0; q < imagelist.Count; q++)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(imagelist[q]);

                    String linkURL = imagelist[q].GetAttribute("src");
                    Console.WriteLine(imagelist[q].Text);

                    URL url = new URL(linkURL);
                    HttpURLConnection http = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
                    http.setConnectTimeout(10000);
                    http.setReadTimeout(20000);


                    int statusCode = http.getResponseCode();
                    Console.WriteLine(linkURL + "and its Status codes is:" + statusCode);
                    if (statusCode == 404 || statusCode == 500)
                    {
                        brokenImagesCount = brokenImagesCount + 1;
                        Console.WriteLine(linkURL + "and its Status codes is:" + statusCode);

                    }



                }

                Console.WriteLine("The total number of broken images are:" + brokenImagesCount);

            }



        }







    }
}
```

can anyone suggest me how to do this but when i am running some other url with no username and password embedded in the URL it shows up the staus code 200 . But when i am testing manually the links its working fine it doesnt have 401 error. kindly help me . thank you very much

Comment: your  HttpURLConnection is a separate session... you are calling directly to a URL and not from the browser.  The browser will add cookies to each request.  You may need to do the same.  (Add the cookies to your  HttpURLConnection request...)  Selenium does have a .getcookie method you can use for this.

Comment: String myCookie = "userId=igbrown;anyOther = 345345";
        httpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection)new URL(linklist[k].GetAttribute("href")).openConnection();
      connection.setRequestMethod("HEAD");
             connection.setRequestProperty("Cookie", myCookie);
                         connection.connect();
                    String response1 = connection.getResponseMessage();
                     
                                
               
I have added like this but still i am getting same thing any suggestions whether its right or wrong can u help me

Comment: once logged in you'll receive a session cookie which is usually going to be set "http-only"... which means Selenium probably can't read it.  You may need to get the cookie by checking the http response from the server after logging in.   Check the browser's inspector or use something like wire shark to see the full set of cookies/request/responses involved.

Comment: it's worth noting that there's many methods of persisting a session and not all are cookie-based.  (using wire-shark should give you a good idea of what method is used, though...)

Comment: btw, there's a project called "Selenium Wire" which seems like it would help you here...  I think it may be for Python only, though: https://github.com/wkeeling/selenium-wire